# How to change a certain fields name in all my documents with mongojs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, field, mongojs

I have a collection, in this collection all my records have, for example, a field named "car". 
I get a new name for this field from my form and i would like to go through all my records and change only the fields name, without changing the value.
I have tried nothing, i can't think any method to do this.
This i what i have:

```
{car:"dodge"}, {car:"ford"}
```

This i what i would like to get:

```
{vehicle:"dodge"}, {vehicle:"ford"}
```

What is the easiest method for this?

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB docs contain a list of all available [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/). In this case you'd want to use [`$rename`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#up._S_rename).

In mongojs:

```
db.coll.update({}, {$rename: {'car': 'vehicle'}}, {multi: true}, callback);
```